# Google Cloud Storage, reads/writes limitations

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, app-engine-flexible

We have an AppEngine **FLEXIBLE** application which stores images in a bucket of the Cloud Storage.
Our application should read each selected image and save several cropped part of the image into the same bucket which original image is stored in. For example we can say crop 5 parts of an images, so 5 new images going to be stored in the bucket and this should be done for many images. the app works perfectly if we choose few images ( 2 to 5 ) with few number of coping part (2-3), but if we select more than 10 images and many cropping parts then after a while we see the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()
```

Any Idea how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Can you please Edit session timeout  information (Increase session timeout) which should be in xml file.

Comment: @AbuSufian :  i have tried to add health check timeout in app.yaml file without any result. It is not because of session timeout. I think there is some limitation regarding the access to storage in few seconds!

Comment: Are you saving the image, or the cropped parts of the image, and then trying to read them again right away?  (Perhaps for validation purposes that they saved correctly?)  Also, are you saving these images across multiple buckets, or just folders within buckets?

Comment: @KevinG : I just crop several parts of an image (user can select multiple images and multiple areas to be cropped) and then save them just into one specific bucket within different folders. to make an example: suppose we have defined 5 areas, and we have selected 10 images, which areas have been applied to those images, then, the number of images which should be saved into the bucket is: 50

Comment: Very interesting... I use GAE flexible to save excel documents to cloud storage, but it's only one at a time.  Before Monday, I'll loop my code to save it 100+ times and see if I can replicate your error. I'll let you know how it goes either way, and I'll post a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the problem by putting the thread to sleep for 5 seconds after each image saving into the storage. I have just added the following line into "for" loop where I save an image:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

So in this case, the procedure gets longer but it won't get blocked by Cloud Storage!